# R question about regression and cross-validation (different p-values for each)

Tags: r, regression, cross-validation

I have an R question. I'm wondering why there is a difference in p-values in the original regression analysis using lm versus in the k-fold cross-validation using the DAAG package.

So, first I run the regression.

```
Model = lm(ExampleData$DependentVariable ~ ExampleData$IV1  + 
           ExampleData$IV2  + ExampleData$IV3  + ExampleData$IV4)
```

This gives me the p-values for the predictors.

```
Coefficients:
                Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)   
(Intercept)     -55.6644    23.4690  -2.372  0.01958 * 
ExampleData$IV1   1.2118     0.6277   1.931  0.05631 .
ExampleData$IV2   6.2636     2.0563   3.046  0.00295 **
ExampleData$IV3   2.1531     0.7490   2.875  0.00492 **
ExampleData$IV4  -5.4468     1.8859  -2.888  0.00473 **
```

Then, I go to cross-validate the model using cv.lm in the DAAG package.

```
cv.lm(df=ExampleData, Model_forCV, m=5)
```

This gives me the cross-validation results along with the p-values for the predictors.

```
Response: DependentVariable
           Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value  Pr(>F)    
IV1         1  26755   26755    3.23 0.07541 .  
IV2         1 104332  104332   12.58 0.00059 ***
IV3         1  36119   36119    4.36 0.03938 *  
IV4         1  69167   69167    8.34 0.00473 ** 
Residuals 102 845806    8292
```

Why are the p-values different?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 reasons why you have slightly diffent p-values.

First, you have two different methods. A standard lm and then a 5 fold cross validation version. The 5 fold cv fits a model on 80% of the observations, then fits in on the other 20%. This will generate slightly different models than the standard lm. And thus you will get slightly different p values.

And second you should also note that the lm model gets it's p values from a t-test and the cv.lm calculates it's p-values from an F-test. That will also give you slightly different p-values.

Answer (score 0):

A 10CV model (10 fold cross-validation) fits e.g. a model on 90% of the observations, and fits it on the remaining hold-out set of 10%. It thus fits a set of slightly different models from the regular lm model and hence we would expect the p-values to be slightly different.